# AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'hide_gridlines'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd

I am trying to run a Python code which was written by my colleague who has now moved out, the same piece of code is running in my machine successfully. But when I run it in other machine it is failing with error

```
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'hide_gridlines'
```

Not sure what this piece of code does, also not sure if it is dependent on any excel packages like xlrd, openpyxl. But I have tried with various versions of xlrd and openpyxl.

Couldn't find any help in the internet. Can you please shed some light?

I am using Python 3.8.5

```
def writeToExcel(ReportPath, SummaryDf, ExecutionDf):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(ReportPath)
    SummaryDf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Report', startcol=1, startrow=1, index=True)
    ExecutionDf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Report',startcol=0, startrow=10, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Report']
    worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)
```

Comment: Can you please show the Worksheet class?

Comment: Worksheets don't have gridlines, charts do. Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Pleae include the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Function `hide_gridlines` was added into XlsxWriter library in version 0.0.4.  Probably, the other machine has older version installed.  Check the currently installed version and upgrade if necessary.

Comment: Without the exception, how do you know which library he's using?

Answer (score 1):

I pip installed the XlsxWriter library. It worked like a charm!